# Gmail Chat "never shown" Google contacts

Tags: gmail, google-talk

Is there a way to get a list of all Google contacts that I have occasionally marked as "never show" in my Gmail Chat?

That is needed to make all of them "auto" one by one with Gmail Chat UI. If one knows an easier way to get that result, please share.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to accomplish this. You can go through each and every contact and apply auto.